# loop over 2 datasets in R to match the value of all rows from one dateset with only one column of another dateset

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement, sapply

I am trying to write a loop in R to perform some iteration on two datasets called `datasetA` and `datasetB`.

`datasetA` has 600 entries and `datasetB` has 200’000 entries.
For each entry in `datasetA`, I want to perform the following:

If the value of `V2` in both datasets are equal,
then calculate the ppm:

`(datasetA$V3 - datasetB$V3) / datasetA$V3 * 1000000`

If the ppm < |10|, then paste the ppm value in `V4` column in `datasetB`, paste the relevant name of `datasetA$V1` in column `V1` of `datasetB`.

Say this is `datasetA` with 600 entries:

```
datasetA<- read.table(text='Alex    1   50.00042
John    1   60.000423
Janine    3   88.000123
Aline    3   117
Mark    2    79.9999')
```

[DatasetA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzlC9.png)

and this is an example of `datasetB` with 200000 entries:

```
datasetB<- read.table(text='NA    1   50.0001    NA
NA    1   50.00032    NA
NA    2   70    NA
NA    2   80    NA
NA    3   88.0004    NA
NA    3   100    NA
NA    3   101    NA
NA    2    102    NA')
```

[DatasetB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HI1qx.png)

The final table should look like this:

```
datasetC <- read.table(text='Alex    1   50.0001    6.459945
Alex    1   50.00032    2.059983
NA    2   70    NA
Mark    2   80    -1.25
Janine    3   88.0004    -3.14772
NA    3   100    NA
NA    3   101    NA
NA    2    102    NA')
```

[The final table should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lZJ6.png)

Comment: where does fourth column of datasetC come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data<-datasetB
for(i in 1:5){
  for(j in 1:8){
    if (datasetA$V2[i]==datasetB$V2[j] & abs((datasetA$V3[i]-datasetB$V3[j])/datasetA$V3[i]*10**6)<10){
      data[j,1]=datasetA[i,1]
      data[j,4]=(datasetA$V3[i]-datasetB$V3[j])/datasetA$V3[i]*10**6
  }}}
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: I am a R noob but let me know if this works for you.

```
library(data.table)

datasetA<- read.table(text='Alex    1   50.00042
John    1   60.000423
                      Janine    3   88.000123
                      Aline    3   117
                      Mark    2    79.9999')
datasetB<- read.table(text='NA    1   50.0001    NA
NA    1   50.00032    NA
NA    2   70    NA
NA    2   80    NA
NA    3   88.0004    NA
NA    3   100    NA
NA    3   101    NA
NA    2    102    NA')

# I renamed columns for my own reference, V1,V2,.. were a bit confusing
names(datasetA) <- c("Name", "ID", "ValueA")
names(datasetB) <- c("V1", "ID", "ValueB", "V4")


# Create a key for each row in datasetB
datasetB$key <- seq(nrow(datasetB))

# Left join A to B on column ID, but first set them as data table
datasetB <- as.data.table(datasetB)
datasetA <- as.data.table(datasetA)
# Using base join but you can also use data table left join see below
datasetC <- merge(x = datasetB, y = datasetA, by = c("ID"), all.x = TRUE)

# Create PPM column
datasetC[, c("ppm") := 1000000*(ValueA - ValueB)/ValueA, ]
# Filter on PPM and keep columns we need
datasetC <- datasetC[abs(ppm) < 10, list(key,Name,ppm)]

# Left join to datasetB on key
setkey(datasetC, key)
setkey(datasetB, key)


datasetB <- datasetC[datasetB]

# Keep columns we need and rename to V1,... as requested
datasetB <- datasetB[, list(V1 = Name, V2 = ID, V3 = ValueB, V4 = ppm)]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer seems to do what the question asks for but I am failing to get 2 of the computed values, final column `V4`.

```
AV2 <- sort(unique(datasetA$V2))
res <- lapply(AV2, function(v2){
  inx_a <- datasetA[['V2']] == v2
  inx_b <- datasetB[['V2']] == v2
  mrg <- merge(datasetA[inx_a, ], datasetB[inx_b, ], by = 'V2')
  ppm <- ((mrg$V3.x - mrg$V3.y)/mrg$V3.x)*1000000
  cbind(mrg[abs(ppm) < 10, c(2, 1, 5)], ppm = ppm[abs(ppm) < 10])
})
res <- do.call(rbind, res)
names(res) <- paste0('V', 1:4)
row.names(res) <- NULL
final <- merge(res, datasetB, by = c('V2', 'V3'), all.y = TRUE)[c(3, 1, 2, 4)]
names(final) <- paste0('V', 1:4)

final
#      V1 V2        V3        V4
#1   Alex  1  50.00010  6.399946
#2   Alex  1  50.00032  1.999983
#3   <NA>  2  70.00000        NA
#4   Mark  2  80.00000 -1.250002
#5   <NA>  2 102.00000        NA
#6 Janine  3  88.00040 -3.147723
#7   <NA>  3 100.00000        NA
#8   <NA>  3 101.00000        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the question is asking for a *join with a complex condition*. This can be implemented using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(datasetA)[setDT(datasetB), on = "V2", {
  ppm <-(x.V3- i.V3) / i.V3 * 1E6
  list(V1 = ifelse(abs(ppm) < 10, x.V1, NA_character_), 
       V2,
       V3 = i.V3,
       V4 = ifelse(abs(ppm) < 10, ppm, NA_real_))
}, mult = "first"]
```

> ```
>        V1 V2        V3        V4
> 1:   Alex  1  50.00010  6.399987
> 2:   Alex  1  50.00032  1.999987
> 3:   <NA>  2  70.00000        NA
> 4:   Mark  2  80.00000 -1.250000
> 5: Janine  3  88.00040 -3.147713
> 6:   <NA>  3 100.00000        NA
> 7:   <NA>  3 101.00000        NA
> 8:   <NA>  2 102.00000        NA
> ```

Here is an alternative approach which updates `datasetB` in place by an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(datasetA)[setDT(datasetB), on = "V2"][
  , V4 := (V3- i.V3) / i.V3 * 1E6][abs(V4) < 10][, i.V1 := NULL]
datasetB[, `:=`(V1 = as.character(V1), V4 = as.double(V4))]
datasetB[tmp, on = .(V2, V3 = i.V3), `:=`(V1 = i.V1, V4 = i.V4)][]
```

> ```
>        V1 V2        V3        V4
> 1:   Alex  1  50.00010  6.399987
> 2:   Alex  1  50.00032  1.999987
> 3:   <NA>  2  70.00000        NA
> 4:   Mark  2  80.00000 -1.250000
> 5: Janine  3  88.00040 -3.147713
> 6:   <NA>  3 100.00000        NA
> 7:   <NA>  3 101.00000        NA
> 8:   <NA>  2 102.00000        NA
> ```